# How to exit recent getopts options?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, getopts

My script:

```
 run() {
     while getopts ":dr" option; do
        case "$option" in
            d) echo "__DEBUG__";;
            r) echo "__RELEASE__";;
        esac
    done
 if [ $option -eq ""]
    then 
      echo "__DEBUG__" ; 
 fi
}
```

Hi, i'm using zsh. When i call **run** without any options

> $ run
>
> $ __ **DEBUG** __

in the first time it's ok and show **DEBUG**

Then i call with option (d/r) and call **run** with no agrument again it show this error

> $ run -r
>
> $ __ **RELEASE** __
>
> $ run
>
> $ run-9: parse error: condition expected: r

I don't know how to fix this, it seem that the while loop still has effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `OPTIND` before the `getopts` call at the start of your function, this will not be done automatically in this case. In bash, it is set to `1` when a shell or shell script starts, but not when a function is called.

This seems to be what [POSIX getopts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) specifies.

> Whenever the shell is invoked, OPTIND shall be initialized to 1.

[zsh getopts](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) behaves differently (thanks @PesaThe):

> `OPTIND` has an initial value of 1, and is normally set to 1 upon entry to a shell function and restored upon exit.

Also, when `getopts` has finished parsing, `option` will be set to `?`, which will not help you determine whether a (valid) option was provided.

Try something like this:

```
run() {
  OPTIND=1
  found=0
  while getopts ":dr" option; do
    case "$option" in
      d) echo "__DEBUG__"; found=1 ;;
      r) echo "__RELEASE__"; found=1 ;;
    esac
  done
  if [ $found -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "__DEBUG__" ; 
  fi
}
```

Or a bit simpler (but not identical to yours, to illustrate):

```
run() {
  OPTIND=1
  mode="__DEFAULT__"
  while getopts ":dr" option; do
    case "$option" in
      d) mode="__DEBUG__" ;;
      r) mode="__RELEASE__" ;;
    esac
  done
  echo "$mode"
}
```

Comment: Quoting [this manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html): *`OPTIND` has an initial value of 1, and is normally set to 1 upon entry to a shell function and restored upon exit*. `zsh` behaves differently than `bash` here. So `OPTIND=1` in `zsh` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. Added some info to the post.

Comment: Got it! Tks all so much